# What is the evaluation order of function arguments?

Tags: go, arguments, evaluation, order-of-execution

I'm using this version of Go:

```
$ go version
go version go1.18 windows/amd64
```

The results are different when struct `A` has only one field and `B` has two or above fields, and it just happens when parameter type is interface.

I'm not sure if that's a bug:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    a := A{}
    m("A", a, SetAI(&a))
    b := B{}
    m("B", b, SetBI(&b))
}

type A struct {
    I int
    S string
}

type B struct {
    I int
}

func SetAI(a *A) A {
    a.I = 10
    return *a
}

func SetBI(b *B) B {
    b.I = 10
    return *b
}

func m(name string, arg1, arg2 interface{}) {
    fmt.Println(name+":", arg1, arg2)
}
```

I expected this output:

```
A: {10} {10}
B: {10} {10}
```

Instead I got this:

```
A: {0 } {10 }
B: {10} {10}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The source of confusion and different output is the order of evaluation of the arguments.

Look at your example:

```
m("A", a, SetAI(&a))
```

This is a function [call](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Calls), the function value and arguments are evaluated in [the usual order](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Order_of_evaluation):

> Otherwise, when evaluating the [operands](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Operands) of an expression, assignment, or [return statement](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Return_statements), all function calls, method calls, and communication operations are evaluated in lexical left-to-right order.
> For example, in the (function-local) assignment
>
> ```
> y[f()], ok = g(h(), i()+x[j()], <-c), k()
> ```
>
> the function calls and communication happen in the order `f()`, `h()`, `i()`, `j()`, `<-c`, `g()`, and `k()`. **However, the order of those events compared to the evaluation and indexing of `x` and the evaluation of `y` is not specified.**

So basically the spec only guarantees that function calls and communication
ops happen from left-to-right.

Your call has arguments `"A"`, `a` and `SetAI(&a)`. There is no guarantee if the second argument `a` is evaluated before the `&a` param passed to `SetAI()`, and this very much matters because `SetAI()` modifies `a`. Since the order is not guaranteed, you can't rely on which will be evaluated first, both order is valid by the spec.

If you make the evaluation explicit by doing a copy of the struct **before**, you get the same result:

```
a := A{}
aCopy := a
m("A", aCopy, SetAI(&a))
b := B{}
bCopy := b
m("B", bCopy, SetBI(&b))
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/EVwk2TydTwS)):

```
A: {0 } {10 }
B: {0} {10}
```

Or if you want the function call to be evaluated first:

```
a := A{}
ap := SetAI(&a)
m("A", a, ap)
b := B{}
bp := SetBI(&b)
m("B", b, bp)
```

This will output `10` for each cases (try this one on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/v3vZfDJB5AL)):

```
A: {10 } {10 }
B: {10} {10}
```